# Removing a class in my "change theme" menu in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've just made a test website with bootstrap and I've got a menu where I've got some highlight effects when you click or hover on a link. I change my theme with a dropdown list with different colors.

If i go downwards in the list of themes everything works fine but if I go to the second element (for example) and then back to the first one the click highlight is the same as the second. I mean, for example, if the first `li` is red theme and the second is blue, if i pick blue the click and hover highlights are blue but if i then switch back to the red theme the hover is red but the click/active highlight is blue.

How can i fix this?

Here's some of the code

HTML

```
<div class="span3 well">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Menu</li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a class="vald" id="home_knapp" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="products_knapp" href="#">Products/Services</a></li>
        <li><a id="about_knapp" href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a id="contact_knapp" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-header">Themes</li>
                <li><a id="default_theme" onclick="default_theme(); return false;" href="#">Default</a></li>
                <li><a id="red_theme" onclick="red_theme(); return false;" href="#">Red</a></li>
                <li><a id="green_theme" onclick="green_theme(); return false;" href="#">Green</a></li>
                <li><a id="yellow_theme" onclick="yellow_theme(); return false;" href="#">Yellow</a></li>
                <li><a id="pink_theme" onclick="pink_theme(); return false;" href="#">Pink</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.default {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #000000;
    background: #04928B;
    background-color: #04928B;
}

.red {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #000000;
    background: #c41414;
    background-color: #c41414;
}
```

Jquery

```
function default_theme() {
    $('html body').css({backgroundColor: '#04928B'});
        $("div .nav li a").click(function(){
            $(".nav .default").removeClass("default");
            $(this).addClass("default");
        });
        $(".nav a").hover(function() {
            $(".nav a").css({background: ''});
            $(this).css({background: '#04928B'});
        }, function() {
            $(".nav a").css({background: ''});
        });
}


function red_theme() {
    $('html body').css({backgroundColor: '#C41414'});
        $("div .nav li a").click(function(){
            $(".nav .red").removeClass("red");
            $(this).addClass("red");
        });
        $(".nav a").hover(function() {
            $(".nav a").css({background: ''});
            $(this).css({background: '#c41414'});

        }, function() {
            $(".nav a").css({background: ''});
        });
}
```

Comment: can u just provide the link of ur page for better understanding

Comment: http://tsnellman.optifiles.fi/playground.php

Comment: Now it's when you click one of the nav-pills in the products/services tab that things start to go wrong when you change theme